# Problem help on real analysis

Tags: real-analysis, normed-spaces

Show the inverse $id^{-1}$ of the identity map $id:(C,|\cdot|)\rightarrow(C\|\cdot\|)$ is not continuous. Where $C$ is the set of continuous function from $[0,1]$ to $\mathbb{R}$, and $|\cdot|$ denotes the sup norm, and $\|\cdot\|=\int^1_0|f(x)|dx$.

I'm basically thinking about this example, pick $f,g\in C$ such that $h(x)=f(x)-g(x)=x^2-\frac{1}{3}$, then pick $\epsilon=\frac{1}{3}$, and for all $\delta>0$, we have $\int^1_0|x^2-1/3|dx<\delta$ but $|h(x)|\geq \epsilon$.

Is this valid proof? Thanks! If not can you point me to a right direction on how to approach this?

Comment: Well, it is not true that $\int^1_0|x^2-\frac13|dx = \frac4{9\sqrt3}$ is less than every positive number…

Comment: @azif00 oh right thanks, I forgot about the absolute value, but am I heading in the right direction in terms of proving the statement?

Comment: And $\operatorname{id} \colon (C,|\cdot|) \to (C,\|\cdot\|)$ is *indeed* continuous: for every $f \in C$, $\|f\| = \int_0^1 |f(x)|dx \leq \int_0^1 |f|dx = |f|$.

Comment: @azif00 Sorry I think I meant to say the inverse of $id$ is not continuous

Comment: You're right, your question was referring to the inverse all along, I didn't read carefully. But leaving that aside, it suffices to find $f \in C$ and a positive number $\varepsilon$ with the property that for every $\delta>0$ you can find $g \in C$ (that depends on $\delta$) such that $\|f-g\|<\delta$ and $|f-g| \geq \varepsilon$.

Comment: Another way to prove this is by recalling that every continuous function is [sequentially continuous](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/sequential_continuity).
Hence, it suffices to find a sequence $(f_n)$ in $C$ such that $f_n \to f$ in $(C,\|\cdot\|)$ but $f_n \not\to f$ in $(C,|\cdot|)$.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For $\DeclareMathOperator\id{Id} \id^{-1}\colon (C, \|-\|) \to (C, |-|)$, consider
$$
f_n (x) = n x^n (1-x), \quad x \in [0,1],
$$
then
$$
f_n(0) = f_n (1) = 0, 
$$
and for all fixed $x \in (0,1)$, $n x^n \to 0 [n \to +\infty]$, so $f_n \to 0$ pointwise, and also
$$
\int_0^1 f_n = n \left( \frac 1{n+1} - \frac 1{n+2}\right) = \frac {n}{(n+1)(n+2)} \xrightarrow {n \to + \infty} 0, 
$$ so $f_n \to 0$ w.r.t. $\|-\|$,
while using AM-GM inequality,
$$
n x^n (1-x) =  x^n (n - nx) \leqslant  \left(\frac n {n+1}\right)^{n+1} \sim \frac 1 {\mathrm e }[n \to +\infty], 
$$ and of course $=$ holds if $x = n - nx$, i.e. $x = n/(n+1) \in (0,1)$,
so
$$
|f_n| = \sup _{[0,1]} f_n = \max _{[0,1]} f_n = \left(1 - \frac 1 {n+1}\right)^{n+1} \xrightarrow {n\to +\infty} \frac 1{\mathrm e}, 
$$
which means $f_n \not \to 0$ w.r.t. $|-|$.

Comment: You haven’t shown that this supremum can be attained. You’ve only shown an upper bound

Comment: @FShrike thanks for pointing it out. I have fixed this.